# How to Create custom Table Rates Shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, shipping-methods, ce-1.9.0.1, table-rates

I need to create 8 different table rate shipping methods which each has some different custom fields. So I can not use `WebShopApps MatrixRate extension` as each shipping method should has different custom fields and here is the module so far I have developed. But the issue is I can not find a way to add `CSV Import/Export` feature to it can anyone help me ?

**app/code/local/Muaw/CustomShippingMethods/Model/Carrier/Abstract.php**

```
abstract class Muaw_CustomShippingMethods_Model_Carrier_Abstract extends Mage_Shipping_Model_Carrier_Flatrate
{
    protected $_code = '';

    public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
    {
        if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active'))
        {
            return false;
        }

        $freeBoxes = 0;
        if ($request->getAllItems())
        {
            foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item)
            {

                if ($item->getProduct()->isVirtual() || $item->getParentItem())
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isShipSeparately())
                {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child)
                    {
                        if ($child->getFreeShipping() && !$child->getProduct()->isVirtual())
                        {
                            $freeBoxes += $item->getQty() * $child->getQty();
                        }
                    }
                }
                elseif ($item->getFreeShipping())
                {
                    $freeBoxes += $item->getQty();
                }
            }
        }
        $this->setFreeBoxes($freeBoxes);

        $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
        if ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'O')
        {
            $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');
        }
        elseif ($this->getConfigData('type') == 'I')
        {
            $shippingPrice = ($request->getPackageQty() * $this->getConfigData('price')) - ($this->getFreeBoxes() * $this->getConfigData('price'));
        }
        else
        {
            $shippingPrice = false;
        }

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($shippingPrice);

        if ($shippingPrice !== false)
        {
            $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');

            $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
            $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

            $method->setMethod($this->_code);
            $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

            if ($request->getFreeShipping() === true || $request->getPackageQty() == $this->getFreeBoxes())
            {
                $shippingPrice = '0.00';
            }


            $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
            $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

            $result->append($method);
        }

        return $result;
    }

    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return array($this->_code=>$this->getConfigData('name'));
    }
}
```

**app/code/local/Muaw/CustomShippingMethods/Model/Carrier/Flatrate2.php**

```
class Muaw_CustomShippingMethods_Model_Carrier_Flatrate2 extends Muaw_CustomShippingMethods_Model_Carrier_Abstract
{
    protected $_code = 'flatrate2';
}
```

**app/code/local/Muaw/CustomShippingMethods/etc/system.xml**

```
<config>
    <sections>
        <carriers translate="label" model="shipping">
            <label>Shipping Methods</label>
            <tab>sales</tab>
            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
            <sort_order>330</sort_order>
            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
            <groups>
                <flatrate translate="label">
                    <label>Flat Rate 1</label>
                    <sort_order>120</sort_order>
                    <fields>
                        <infotext translate="label">
                            <label>Info Text (supports HTML)</label>
                            <frontend_type>editor</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </infotext>
                    </fields>
                </flatrate>

                <flatrate2 translate="label">
                    <label>Flat Rate 2</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>121</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <active translate="label">
                            <label>Enabled</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </active>
                        <name translate="label">
                            <label>Method name</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </name>
                        <price translate="label">
                            <label>Price</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>5</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </price>
                        <handling_type translate="label">
                            <label>Calculate Handling Fee</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>shipping/source_handlingType</source_model>
                            <sort_order>7</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </handling_type>
                        <handling_fee translate="label">
                            <label>Handling Fee</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>8</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </handling_fee>
                        <sort_order translate="label">
                            <label>Sort order</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sort_order>
                        <title translate="label">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </title>
                        <type translate="label">
                            <label>Type</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_flatrate</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </type>
                        <sallowspecific translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to applicable countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <frontend_class>shipping-applicable-country</frontend_class>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_shipping_allspecificcountries</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </sallowspecific>
                        <specificcountry translate="label">
                            <label>Ship to Specific countries</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>91</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_country</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </specificcountry>
                        <showmethod translate="label">
                            <label>Show method if not applicable</label>
                            <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>92</sort_order>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </showmethod>
                        <specificerrmsg translate="label">
                            <label>Displayed Error Message</label>
                            <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>80</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </specificerrmsg>
                        <infotext translate="label">
                            <label>Info Text (supports HTML)</label>
                            <frontend_type>editor</frontend_type>
                            <sort_order>90</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                        </infotext>
                    </fields>
                </flatrate2>
             ..............
            </groups>
        </carriers>
    </sections>
</config>
```